# I18 Url generator error using record as locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I18n is not generating url correctly when not using key and value in path params.

Working: `edit_user_registration_path(id:9)`
`"/en/users/edit?id=4"`

Not working: `edit_user_registration_path(current_user)`

```
No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"registrations", :locale=>#<User id: 4, email: "john.doe@gmail.com", locale: "en", created_at: "2020-12-06 17:10:10"">}, possible unmatched constraints: [:locale]
```

**Why does the generator is not using the default rails behaviour here ?**

```
ApplicationController

 before_action :set_locale

 private

    def set_locale
      I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
    end

    def default_url_options
      { locale: I18n.locale }
    end
```

```
 routes.rb
  scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    root to:'pages#home'
    devise_for :users, skip: :omniauth_callbacks, controllers: { registrations: :registrations }
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using `edit_user_registration_path(current_user.id)` instead of passing the `current_user` object itself should work. Check this once.